# How to send e-mail through VBA without Outlook

Tags: vba, email, smtp

I'm trying to send email through SMTP in VBA, but is returning error.

```
Dim CDOmsg As CDO.Message
Set CDOmsg = New CDO.Message

With CDOmsg.Configuration.Fields
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "myemail@gmail.com"
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "mypass"
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smptserverport") = 465
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2 'NTLM method
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60
    .Update
End With
' build email parts
With CDOmsg
    .Subject = "the email subject"
    .From = "myemail@gmail.com"
    .To = "mailto@gmail.com"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .TextBody = "the full message body goes here. you may want to create a variable to hold the text"
End With
CDOmsg.Send
Set CDOmsg = Nothing
```

The error is on CDOmsg.Send. I've tried to send with Gmail and Yahoo Mail, but I get this same error.

> Error code: -2147220973(80040213)
>
> Error description: The transport failed to connect to the server

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following but don't forget to tick the checkbox for 'Microsoft CDO for Windows 2000 Library'

```
Function email(ByVal sender_email As String, _
            ByVal email_message As String, _
            ByVal email_message2 As String, _
            ByVal reply_address As String, _
            ByVal sender_name As String)       

    Dim Mail As New Message

    Dim Cfg As Configuration

    Set Cfg = Mail.Configuration

    'SETUP MAIL CONFIGURATION FIELDS
    Cfg(cdoSendUsingMethod) = cdoSendUsingPort
    Cfg(cdoSMTPServer) = 'SMTP
    Cfg(cdoSMTPServerPort) = 'SMTPport
    Cfg(cdoSMTPAuthenticate) = cdoBasic
    Cfg(cdoSMTPUseSSL) = True
    Cfg(cdoSendUserName) = 'sender_email
    Cfg(cdoSendPassword) = 'password
    Cfg.Fields.Update

    'SEND EMAIL
    With Mail
        .From = 'sender_name & sender_email
        .ReplyTo = 'reply_address
        .To = 'receiver
        .CC = 'carbonCopy
        .BCC = 'blindCopy
        .Subject = 'SubjectLine
        .HTMLBody = 'email_message & email_message2 
        .Attachments.Add attFilePath
        .Send
    End With
```